# How can I prevent concurrency while writing and reading from my DB?

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency, innodb, backend

I have a table with user login information and registration too. So when two users consecutively try to add their details:

1. Will both the writes clashes and the table wont be updated?
2. Using threads for these writes is bad idea. As for each write a new thread would be created and it would clog the server. Is the server responsible for it to manage on its own?
3. Is locking the table a good idea?

My back-end runs on PHP/Apache with MySQL (InnoDB) for the database.

Comment: This question creates a hypothetical problem which doesn't exist in reality.

Comment: Why is locking not a real problem? Just because relational databases are built to answer the question already doesn't mean it isn't a real and fundamental problem. It just means there's already an answer and the OP doesn't need to take any further action.

Answer (score 4):

Relational databases are designed to avoid these kinds of conditions. You don't need to worry about them unless you are designing your own relational database from scratch.

In short, just know this: Any time a write is initiated, there is a row-level lock. If another transaction wants to write to that same row, then it has to wait until the first transaction releases the lock. This is a fundamental part of relational databases. You don't need to add a lock because they've already thought of that :)

You can read more about how MySQL performs locks to avoid deadlocking and other transaction errors [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-locking.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you're really paranoid about this, or perhaps you are doing multiple things when you register a user and need them done atomically, you might want to look at using Transactions in MySQL.  There's a decent write-up about Transactions here http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-transaction.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN;
do related reads/writes to the data
COMMIT;
```

Inside that "transaction", the connection sees a consistent view of the data, and blocks anyone else from messing with that view.

There are exceptions.  The main one is

```
BEGIN
SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;
fiddle with the values SELECTed
UPDATE ...;  -- and change those values
COMMIT;
```

The `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE` announces what should not be tampered with.  If another connection wants to mess with the same rows, it will have to wait until your `COMMIT`, at which time he may find that things have changed and he will need to do something different.  But, in general, this avoids a "deadlock" wherein two transactions are stepping on each other so badly that one has to be "rolled back".

With techniques like this, the "concurrency" is prevented only briefly and relatively precisely.  That is, if two connections are working with *different* rows, *both* can proceed -- there is no need to "prevent concurrency".